# So that + adjective?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, usage

How would you translate something like “so that you are/can be X”?

I bought this so that he’ll be safe.

I want to do this for you so that you’re happy!

Comment: Voted to close due to this being a translation request. However, I would suggest ため（に） or ～よう（に） like examples shown [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=so+that).

Comment: @BJCUAI what i don’t understand is howように/ために work with adjectives and the copula haha. 彼が安全だように、これを買った？is that correct?

Comment: In that case, I suggest re-framing your original question so it is no longer off-topic.

Comment: That’s incorrect. だ can’t be before ように. 彼の安全のためにこれを買った will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments you would use ように/ために.
As for the question of how to combine this with adjectives and the copula you would normally use the adverbial form of the word in question. For example:

> 彼が安全にいられるようにこれを買った
>
> 美味しくするために塩を入れた

For the copula you can use である (which is another form of the copula) but I think in most cases なる and いる does the job better

Comment: `美味しくなるために塩を入れた` -- 「美味しく**するために**塩を入れた」か「美味しく**なるように**塩を入れた」って言うと思うんですけど・・

Comment: @Chocolate 確かにそっちのほうが自然！ありがとう